# How can I fix this pom.xml problem? (coonection to the database)

Tags: mysql, database, maven, jpa, java-11

Im working with: MySQL Workbench 8.0, Spring Tool Suite 3.9.7 with JDK 11. (This is everything that I have)

Id like to create the database connection, but I get this ERROR:

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Közép-európai téli idõ' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

The full ERROR is here: https://hastebin.com/zimibuvafa.sql

**Applications properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=adam
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The password, username, test name is correct.

**pom.xml**: https://hastebin.com/oyufeporit.xml

Finally, I created a correct entity package with the entity class. (because os the connection) --> @Entity, Getters-Setters etc.

Thank you for everything.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3030/db?test1=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

and add another line `spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: It started, JVM is running, but unfortunately doesnt create the table in the workbench.
New ERROR:

Comment: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table name (id bigint not null auto_increment, names varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Comment: Anyway, Thank you Avijit!